# Google Cloud SQL Docker Proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I am trying to connect to my Cloud SLQ (Postgres) instance from my local environment (OSX) using the Google Cloud SQL Docker Proxy as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-docker#tcp-sockets). When running the proxy I get:

```
google: could not find default credentials.
```

Note that I am running gcloud on my local environment within the right project and having authenticated through the `application-default` login. I understand that in similar questions this is what solved the issue however this is not my case.

Comment: Clarification...when you say `application-default` how do you mean? Did you run `gcloud auth application-default login`? Or did you print a bearer token? If you run `gcloud auth list` do you see the accounts you expect, and is the one you want `ACTIVE`?

Comment: Oh, just saw you're running the Docker example, not just connecting. Do you have a service account? The token you get from `application-default print-access-token` is different than what you need. You need an IAM service account key. Because it's a Docker container, I THINK you might be able to do it by running `gcloud auth application-default login` in the Docker container's build step, but that's...a hack since it'll give you end-user credentials, which isn't the recommended way to use the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I did create a service account as specified in the documentation. The account has the cloud sql admin role and I am using its JSON key.

Comment: Ok, the error message implies that either 1) you aren't passing the `-credential_file` in that docker run command (note, there's two places you're specifying the credentials file in that command, the second one will cause the proxy to look for default credentials) or 2) the path you're specifying in the -v argument to path to the cred file isn't correct. So in either of those cases, the proxy will try to find default credentials (e.g. the path set in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var), but it's still unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the absolute path of the key file solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good resource for this issue: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy

Look at where you specify PATH_TO_KEY_FILE here:

```
   docker run -d \
      -v PATH_TO_KEY_FILE:/config \
      -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 \
      gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.19.1 /cloud_sql_proxy \
      -instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306 \
      -credential_file=/config
```